# Plot coordinates on image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have image which is display dynamically. For this image i have coordinate value which is already stored in database.Now using this coordinate value i want to mark on image.
 
Here is my jquery code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Section.aspx/GetImageData",
           //data: '',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "dataSecName": name }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                   alert("Success");
                   var imgval = JSON.parse(data.d);
                   $.each(imgval, function (i, jsondata) {
                   $("#imgDiv").empty();
                     //console.log(jsondata.ImageName);
                    console.log(jsondata.XCordinate);
                    console.log(jsondata.YCordinate);
                    var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
                    img.attr('src', "../Administration/imageHotspot/" + jsondata.ImageName);
                    img.appendTo('#imgDiv');
                    $("#dynamic").height(500);
                    $("#dynamic").width(500);
   });
});
```

Here image get display successfully. now i want to use this coordinate value plot on this image. 
I have write the code to plot but nothing gets work

```
  $.each(imgval, function (i, jsondata) {
                            //$("body").append(
                            $("#dynamic").append(
                                  $('<div></div>').css({
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                      top: jsondata.YCordinate + 'px',
                                      left: jsondata.XCordinate + 'px',
                                    //top: event.pageY + 'px',
                                    //left: event.pageX + 'px',
                                    width: '10px',
                                    height: '10px',
                                    background: '#dd4b39',
                                    'border-radius': '10px'
                                })
                            );

                        });
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue along with a **clear problem description** - *nothing gets work* is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: As the div you are inserting had an "absolute" position, the "#dynamic" thing, which is it's parent, should also have it's css position set. ie. Add `#dynamic {position: relative}` and the absolute positioning of the inserted div should be as expected.

Comment: @2pha i have tried this one sir but the marker is not shown on the specific position on the image. It display below the image not on the image.